# Enforce tag name in svn hook using shell

Tags: bash, shell, svn

I am trying to write a pre-commit hook script to Enforcing tag naming convention like                       `<application>_<project>_<version>_<iteration>`
using a shell script.
Can anyone guide me to a doc/link which I can go through and can create one? I have already gone through many links but didn't work for me.

I am trying something like this

```
ERROR=$SVNLOOK changed $REPO -t $REV |$EGREP "^A.+?/([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/\1-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?-(dev|rc[0-9]+|final)/.*$" |$WC -l
```

Need help in regex(EGREP) part so that I can create it.

Comment: sorry for replying late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
  $EGREP -q "^A...([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/" && \
  ! $EGREP -q "^A...([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/\1-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?-(dev|rc[0-9]+|final)/.*$" && \
  echo wrong tag pattern >&2 && exit 1
```

The idea here is, if a line matches `^A...([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/`, but it doesn't match `^A...([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/\1-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?-(dev|rc[0-9]+|final)/.*$`, then abort the commit.